# How do I specify DEV or PROD in Vite?

Tags: vite

In the [Vite documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html) I read the following:

> import.meta.env.PROD: {boolean} whether the app is running in production.

> import.meta.env.DEV: {boolean} whether the app is running in development (always the opposite of import.meta.env.PROD)

However, I can't find how these variables are defined or configured.

When I build the application [`npm run build` or `npm run build --mode production`] this is what the value of import.meta.env is when I log it:

```
{
    BASE_URL: "/", 
    MODE: "production", 
    DEV: true, 
    PROD: false
}
```

*Which is also rather confusing since the mode is set to production, but the PROD value is not.*

How can I specify the PROD or DEV value? Setting `PROD=true` in my .env file is not resolving the problem (as expected).

In case it helps, I am running Vite version 4.4.4

Answer (score 1):

I found [this commit](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/pull/14124/commits/83963266aef32004a99037a56c084351904d2663) with a request to update the documentation:

> **`import.meta.env.PROD`**: {boolean} whether the app is running in production (running the dev server with `NODE_ENV='production'` or running an app built with `NODE_ENV='production'`).

This clarifies how the PROD value can be set, by setting NODE_ENV to production. Since DEV is the opposite of PROD, setting NODE_ENV to production will set DEV to false.